# startActivity with intent results in black screen

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

within Activity the viewChange is executed and the intent received is also not null. The problem is, that there are no error messages displayed. Also there is no regularity on which the error occours. Sometimes the view chage is done correctly, but most of the time it's not done, which results in a black screen.
Sure I'd prefer to remove the issue, but if there is a way to check if the screen is now null and retry the startactivity that would also be an acceptable solution for now.

The InteractionManager.handleIntent function only creates and returns an intent, i've debugged through it, everything works as expected. (it's just a when statement)

```
/**
 * Update function that handles timer & content changes
 * @param observable Observable that raised the call
 * @param property property that is given by the observable
 * */
override fun update(observable: Observable?, property: Any?) {
    runOnUiThread {
        if (property is ViewEvent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received Event: $property")
            if (checkForChange(property)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OK, checked for view change")
                InteractionManager.deleteObserver(this)
                Log.d(TAG, "OK, view dispached from Observer...")
                val it = InteractionManager.handleIntent(property, this)
                if(it==null)
                    Log.e(TAG,"!!!ERROR ERROR INTENT IS NULL!!!")
                startActivity(it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                Log.d(TAG, "OK, view change done")
            } else {/*SHOW ALERT WINDOW*/
            }
        } else if (property is Message) {
            synchronized(isCreated) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Gathering message: $property")
                if (isCreated) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Caling display function from update")
                    processDisplayContent(property)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "(update) display not created yet")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```